# Spatial domain and frequency domain

Tags: image-processing

I am confused between spatial domain and frequency domain. I can't really differentiate them. I know spatial domain deals with image plan. Frequency domain deals with intensity I guess. Here is my doubt what we are actually dealing in spatial domain? Spatial domain works on pixels directly and a pixel contains the intensity value of each colour at that point/pixel. So if we change values of pixels we are actually dealing with frequency domain here.
We do spacial enhancement like negative of image in which we kind of interchange the intensity values from dark to light or light to dark.

In spatial shouldn't we deal with the position or something like that as the word suggests?

This might be a foolish question but I am really confused between them. Please explain me in details what we are actually dealing with in both these domains like what values/properties we are changing in both these domains. I have read a lot of articles but none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a broad question and before diving into the image frequency domain, you should study more about signal (1D signal) frequencies, then come back to the image.

Although I try to put these concepts in a few words:

Spatial domain is the regular domain that you know for working with an image. Pixel positions, intensities, width and height of the image, median filter, mean filter, morphology etc, are all spatial-domain-related definitions.

Frequency domain on the other hand, is about the **changes** in the intensities along with the pixel positions. The more the values of the pixels' intensities are different from each other, the more frequencies it has.

Usually people show the frequency domain like an image with the size of the original image and I think that's why you are confused between these two concepts. If you want to show the frequencies of a regular image, it is like an image with a much bigger height and width. The pixel positions in the frequency domain are the frequency value in the spatial domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion comes from the wrong assumption that the frequency domain "deals with intensity".

The spatial domain represents a signal [image] by the intensities at every sample [pixel]. Pixels are treated independently.

The frequency domain represents a signal as a superposition of sinusoids of various amplitudes, frequencies and phases. A given sinusoid covers the whole image.

This representation has nothing to do with our daily experience and is an important contribution of the theory of linear systems, involving the superposition principle and the concept of orthogonal functions.